# TABLA CON JQUERY

Tags: jquery

Cambiar el color de borde y de fondo a las celdas que su valor sea mayor a 5, utilizando el método **.each()**, sin agregar clases ni ids.

[image: tabla]

***index.html***

```
<table id="proyecto">
                  <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>6</td>
                    <td>9</td>
                  </tr>
  </table>
```

***Jquery:***

```
function tarea(){
$('#proyecto tr').each(function(){
        var celdas = $(this).find('td');
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realmente lo único que te falta hacer es capturar el contenido de cada celda y condicionar su valor, así:

```js
function tarea(){
  $('#proyecto tr td').each(function(){
    var valor = $(this).text();
    
    if(valor > 5){
      $(this).css('background', 'red')
    }
  })
}

tarea();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="proyecto">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: muchas gracias :) me ha servido sos un crack